# Unexpected Output: register_activation_hook with namespace

Tags: errors, activation

I encounter a weird error while using the `register_activation_hook` and `namespace`.

> The plugin generated 236 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

I get this error even with this simple plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Sample Plugin
 *
 */
namespace Sample;

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'sp_activate' );
function sp_activate() {

}
```

If I remove the `namespace` the error does not occur. Do I miss something? What is wrong here?

Comment: That's the entirety of the "plugin" that is causing the message you are seeing?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you differently ask it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we are outside the `Sample` namespace, we should call the function by `\Sample\sp_activate()`, so please try the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Sample Plugin
 * Version:     0.0.2
 */

namespace Sample;

\register_activation_hook( __FILE__, '\Sample\sp_activate' );

function sp_activate() {

}
```

If something is printed out during the plugin activation it will result in unexpected output message. If you use for example `echo 'Hello';` in your activation function, it will generate such a message of 5 characters.

You should consider using [`WP_DEBUG_LOG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and log the errors into a file, to see what kind of errors you're getting there.

I hope this helps.